# Deleting all datasets in a library

Tags: sas

This probably has a really simple answer. How would I go about deleting all the datasets in a library? I did something like

```
proc datasets library=lib;
   delete _all_;
quit;
```

but that just tries to delete the dataset called `_all_`. Do I have to manually list all the datasets in the `delete` command?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the kill option in the proc dataset to delete all files in a library.

```
proc datasets library=lib kill;
run;
quit;
```